# VS Code is freezing on VirtualBox with Lubuntu 20.04 Lxqt

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, crash, freeze

I'm using **Lubuntu 20.04** on **VirtualBox**. It uses Lxqt which has become the standard since Lubuntu version 19.
My problem is **Visual Studio Code**. It is freezing the virtual machine everytime. I've already tried initialization options that are usually recommended *(--disable-gpu)* and I've also tried to change some settings for the virtual machine.
The problem still occurs. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Its a known issue with electron, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83996

Comment: Ok. I'll try to re-install to check if solves the problem.

Comment: I installed this version and i will test again:    Version: 1.46.0
Commit: a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321
Date: 2020-06-10T08:59:04.923Z
Electron: 7.3.1
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-37-generic snap

Comment: The problem continues... the whole screen freezes while i'm tipying..

Comment: This problem still persists for me on Lubuntu 18.10 on VirtualBox and VSCode 1.15.1

Comment: try the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1301938/799513